# Statistical tests

Tags: statistics

Some students were asked how they prefer be informed.
The results of the research are below:
television: 22
radio: 15
newspaper: 26
internet: 15
The researchers want to know if the students prefer a specific way to be informed or not.

Which statistical test should i use and how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test : Pearson chi-square test, but the events must be mutually exclusive with total probability 1. That means, a student should choose one and only one option among radio newpaper and internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to determine whether the three methods are equally
popular, or confirm to some pre-specified distribution on the four
methods, then a chi-squared test is appropriate.

It must be true that $22 + 15 + 26 + 15 = 78 = n$ subjects each
chose exactly one method as favorite.

We test the null hypothesis is $H_0: p_T = p_R = p_N = p_I = 1/4$
against the alternative than not all methods are equally popular.
Then, under $H_0,$ we expect $E = 78/4 = 19.5$ responses favoring
each method. The question is whether the observed values
$X = (22, 15, 26, 15)$ are far enough from 19.5 each to reject $H_0.$

Under $H_0,$ the test statistic $Q = \sum_{i=1}^4 \frac{(X_i = E)^2}{E}$
has approximately a chi-squared distribution with $k - 1 = 3$ degrees
of freedom.  For our data $Q = 4.54.$

```
X = c(22, 15, 26, 15)
Q = sum((X - 19.6)^2/19.6);  Q
## 4.542857
```

The PDF of $Chisq(\nu = 3)$ is shown below. The vertical blue line
is at 4.52. The area under the curve to the right of that line is
the P-value = 21.2% of the test.

[image]

If the P-value were below 5% we
would reject $H_0.$ (Put in another way, the 'critical value' for
the test is 7.8147; we would not reject $H_0$ unless $Q \ge 7.8147.$
The critical value cuts 5% from the right tail of $Chisq(3); it can
be found in printed tables of the chi-squared distribution.)

Although the observed values $X = (22, 15, 26, 15)$ may not seem
to be 'close' to 19's or 20's, they are close enough not to be
significant evidence against $H_0.$

*Cautionary Note:* If we had $n = 312$ and observed preference counts
$X = (88,  60, 104,  60)$ then *proportions* in the four categories
would be exactly the same as for your data (all counts just multiplied by 4).
But then $Q = 176.6$ and $Q$ is still compared with the distribution $Chisq(3).$
The conclusion would be overwhelmingly in favor or rejecting $H_0.$
It is neither relative proportions nor degrees of freedom that tell
the whole story! Sample size $n$ also matters in a way that might not
be immediately obvious.

Comment: I see you are new to the site. Generally, questions will get the best reception here if you give brief info about the course, recent possibly relevant topics studied, and also say what you have tried and where you are having trouble. (I recall you tried to add something, which might have been included as an edit to your Question, but that is gone now.) Because your Q is 'on hold' now, you will not get additional Answers. If my Answer is what you need, please click to Accept. If you need something else, please leave a Comment below my Answer, and I will try to clarify within a day.